# running openvpn in a corretto docker image fails with security issue

Tags: java, docker, openvpn, corretto

I have installed openvpn into a corretto docker image thusly:

```
FROM amazoncorretto
RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel
RUN yum -y install p7zip openvpn
```

I get an error when it tries to see the TUN device.

```
ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

So after a little reading I tried to create the /dev/net/tun device.
Close, but no dice.

```
mkdir /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
chmod 600 /dev/net/tun (tried with and without this).
```

Now executing `openvpn --config /opt/settings/private.ovpn` I get a new permission error that I cannot seem to resolve:

```
ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
```

Is there a way to resolve this?
Do I have to use a **different javac container** or is there a way to get **corretto** working?

**edit**
I have also tried installing `yum -y install NetworkManager-vpnc`.
Some suggestions indicate that it needs to be executed with `sudo` so I `yum -y install sudu` and tried to run openvpn using that, same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable privileged mode on the container?